# Get custom stock product quantity

Tags: magento2

I use this code to retrieve product quantity by given id

```
$stockItem = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');
$productId =  10858;
$productStock = $stockItem->get($productId);
$productStock->getData();
```

This code work and return this results

```
array (
  'item_id' => '10858',
  'product_id' => '10962',
  'stock_id' => '1',
  'qty' => '0.0000',
  'min_qty' => '0.0000',
  ...
)
```

But I need to retrieve information by stock_id = 2 instead of default stock (id: 1)
There's a way to do this, using this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way, you can get the MSI qty using stock ID:

```
/** @var \Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetStockItemDataInterface $getStockItemData */
$getStockItemData = $obj->create('Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetStockItemDataInterface');


$stockId = 55;
// Stock items where QTY and Salable status
$stockItemData = $getStockItemData->execute('ProduectSKU', $stockId);
$stockItemDataQty = $stockItemData[\Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetStockItemDataInterface::QUANTITY] ?? 0;
```

For the default config by stock, try the following way:

```
$getStockItemConfiguration = $obj->create('Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\GetStockItemConfigurationInterface');
$stockItemConfiguration = $getStockItemConfiguration->execute('ProduectSKU', $stockId);
$manageStock = $stockItemConfiguration->isManageStock();
```

**Note:** *Avoid using object manager, this is not recommended.*

Answer (score 0):

although I don't recommend using object manager but try this way in product detail

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);
    $count = 0; 
    foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) { 
        $productQty = $productStockObj->getStockItem($child->getId());
        round($count+=$productQty->getData('qty'));
    } 
    echo $count;
} else {
    $productQty = $productStockObj->getStockItem($product->getId());
    echo round($productQty->getData('qty'));
}
echo __('pcs');
```

in list products

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
forearch($_productCollection as $_product){                      
    $productTypeInstance = $_product->getTypeInstance();
    if ($_product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($_product);
        $count = 0; 
        foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) { 
           $productQty  = $productStockObj->getStockItem($child->getId());
            round($count+=$productQty->getData('qty'));
        } 
        echo $count;
    } else {
        $productQty = $productStockObj->getStockItem($_product->getId());
        echo round($productQty->getData('qty'));
    }
}
```

write handler function in block first instead of object manager in phtml file